# Finding a matching row in a log events

Tags: postgresql

I have a database that keeps track of website activity.  Users on the site open a document, and then save the document multiple times.   What I want is the open time and the last save time per document .  If it matters, this is in postgress.

I have tried using lag, but lag requires you to indicate how many rows to go back, and I don't know.  Here are two examples

| Username | Document Name | Event Name | Event Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | d1 | Open | 2021-01-08 00:48:29.384 |
| Test1 | d1 | save | 2021-01-08 00:49:29.384 |
| Test1 | d1 | save | 2021-01-08 00:51:29.384 |
| Test1 | d1 | save | 2021-01-08 00:55:29.384 |
| Test1 | d2 | Open | 2021-02-08 00:55:29.384 |
| Test1 | d2 | save | 2021-02-09 00:59:29.384 |
| Test1 | d2 | save | 2021-02-09 01:59:29.384 |
| Test1 | d2 | save | 2021-02-09 02:59:29.384 |
| Test1 | d1 | Open | 2021-02-10 02:59:29.384 |
| Test1 | d1 | Save | 2021-02-11 02:59:29.384 |
| Test1 | d1 | Save | 2021-02-12 02:59:29.384 |

So for this list  test1,d1 open time 2021-01-08 00:48:29.384 and last save 2021-01-08 00:55:29.384.

AND
test1,d1,2021-02-10 02:59:29.384 last save was2021-02-12 02:59:29.384

and for

test1,d2, 2021-02-08 00:55:29.384 and save was 2021-02-09 02:59:29.384

I can't figure out a way to get the open and then the ordered last save for that open event.

Comment: Please add the desired query result to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase the question:

You are looking for the highest event_time with the event "Save" that is bigger than the "current" Open event but smaller than the *next* Open for that document and user.

I am not sure if there is a more efficient solution, but the following does return what you want (as far as I understand)

```
select o.username, o.document_name, o.event_time as open_time, 
       s.event_time as last_saved
from activity o
  left join lateral (
     select max(event_time) as event_time
     from activity a2
     where a2.event_name = 'Save'
       and a2.username = o.username 
       and a2.document_name = o.document_name        
       and a2.event_time >= o.event_time
       and a2.event_time <= coalesce((select max(a3.event_time)
                                      from activity a3
                                      where a3.username = o.username
                                        and a3.document_name = o.document_name
                                        and a3.event_time > o.event_time
                                        and a3.event_name = 'Open'), a2.event_time)
  ) as s on true
where o.event_name = 'Open'
;
```

The `left join lateral` is necessary, because there might not be a Save event for an Open event.

The `coalesce()` on the sub-query to find the "next" Open event is necessary, because there might not be a "next" Open event after the one from the "current" row.

I *think* two partial indexes would help performance here:

```
create index on activity (username, document_name, event_time)
where event_name = 'Save';

create index on activity (username, document_name, event_time)
where event_name = 'Open';
```

But you will have to verify this with your actual data.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/m6wl_B0I)

(Note that I had to fix the spelling of Open/Save to make it consistent)